# Laravel find user from 2 models

Tags: php, laravel

How can I search for user in 2 different tables?

Example:

```
$user = 
// either
User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
// or this
Seller::where('email', $request->email)->first();
```

Comment: are there any relationship between them??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon no.

Comment: so look in the first model. if not found look in the second model??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So look for the user existence in the first model. If not found look in the second model.

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
if (!$user) {
    $user = Seller::where('email', $request->email)->first();
}

if ($user) {
    return $user;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

as Tim suggested in the comment, if you are using php 7+, you can use null coalescing operator to do it in one line

```
return User::where('email', $request->email)->first() ?? Seller::where('email', $request->email)->first() ?? 'not found / 0 / or anything';
```

Comment: just null checking is enough.

Comment: it says `0: The provided credentials are incorrect.` it's refer to email address. (maybe it just looking in users table? because the user i'm trying to access is in sellers table)

Comment: the seller table has email column??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon  `$return user` should be `return $user`.

Comment: @vinod my bad. it's a typo

Comment: If you're on PHP 7+, you can one-line this: `return User::where('email', $request->email)->first() ?? Seller::where('email', $request->email)->first() ?? 0` (although the `?? 0` seems unnecessary when `null` is falsey enough when compared to `0`)